# How to publish a Zend Framework 2 module on modules.zendframework.com?

Tags: module, zend-framework2

[modules.zendframework.com](http://modules.zendframework.com/) is the "App Store" / "Market Place" for Zend Framework 2 and provides already more than 200 modules to download. I thought, everything I need to publish my module there is a GitHub account. But now I cannot find out, how to "upload"/"share" my module there.

Comment: Not a programming question. Ask for it in IRC #zftalk @ freenode.net - furthermore: https://github.com/zendframework/modules.zendframework.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this moment only modules published in GitHub are supported

Comment: Yes, it's right. But for example I have a ZF2 module on GitHub. How can I publish it now on modules.zendframework.com?

Comment: The app try to find the file "Module.php" inside of your repo https://github.com/zendframework/modules.zendframework.com/blob/master/module/ZfModule/src/ZfModule/Service/Module.php#L68